# The post request works with postman but not with nuxt axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have tried some times and looking for the best result in some similar questions but I have not got any rational result, I have got response with postman and js AJAX but not with axios. my header request is as bellow:

```
:authority: www.sample.com 
:method: POST 
path: /api/v1/contact 
:scheme: https 
accept: application/json, text/plain 
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br 
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8 
content-length: 549 
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
origin: http://localhost:3000 
referer: http://localhost:3000/contact-us 
sec-fetch-dest: empty 
sec-fetch-mode: cors 
sec-fetch-site: cross-site 
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36
```

any idea? thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Can you please add more details like any error/response, CORS settings etc ? Request hitting server or blocked due to CORS?

Comment: I do not have any CORS error and when I post some payloads to the endpoint the backed does not see the payloads and I get 400 error.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: yes, this problem brings from the backend framework which is CI `due to request content-type. I made a mistake to define that in my request